# Python minimal memory overlay code or remove used code?

Tags: python, initialization

I am writing a python daemon, and I'd like to minimize the amount of memory left after initializing stuff.

Once some code had been run (it will only be run once), is there a way dispose of code that has been used?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: This feels like premature optimization to me.  Do you have any example code of things you think will remain in memory longer than they ought to?  Deleting something in the local namespace using `del` is only going to remove it from memory if there aren't other references - if it's in use by anything else in the daemon it'll stick around anyway.

Comment: I have a data acquisition board I want to access every second, and accumulate values in memory. I will retrieve the accumulators using inter process communications. During setup of the daemon, I have a config file I parse to populate lists and things. Once the lists are properly populated, I have no further use for the init code. More then half the program is initialization, the remaining 'meat' will be quite small. I hate to leave all that init code in memory since it will never get used more then once.

Comment: If you're properly making use of scope, most of the things done during initialization should be cleared up by the garbage collector when they go out of scope.  You still haven't posted any code to diagnose.

Comment: I started to trim down my code so I could include it as an example, and my mind began to drift to the inter-process communications part. In the end, I want 3 programs handling the data acquisition, a daemon, a program to simply display the current statuses from the daemon, and a third program to change and configure the daemon as needed. I am thinking shared memory, then that may solve my issues. The daemon can start up, allocate shared memory, and wait till the configuration program does the init. then the daemon can continue. I'm thinking Python may not be best choice for the daemon.